Why isn't BottomAppBar white?
I have an ordinary scaffold:
Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
            TopAppBar(title = {
                Column {
                    Text(text= "hello"))
                }
            })
        },
        bottomBar = {
            BottomAppBar(
                containerColor = Color.White
            ) {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {
                    Text(text="first")
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(10.dp))
                    Text(text="Second")
                }
            }
        }
    ){
        Text(text = "text", modifier = Modifier.padding(it))
    }

i expect BottomAppBar will be white but for some reason it is not:

I even changed surface and background color to white in material theme but the result is the same. Why ?

It's white when I try it, with or without using a theme containerColor = Color.White is applied as it should, differently from what your screenshot shows. There must be something else going on. Have you tried this in a newly created project? Then you can compare what's different.

Btw., also your other example from this double post doesn't reproduce the problem, it's still white for me. Have you followed the advice from my previous comment? What was the result?

@Leviathan yes I did. The result is the same

When I use "Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 2" and create a new project with "Empty Activity" as template without changing any of the preselected settings, and then replace the call to Greeting with either the code from this question or the one from the other and use the autofix to add the missing import statements it shows me a bar with a white background. Did you do the exact same steps? Nothing more, nothing less?

@Leviathan thank you a lot for your tries to help me. I got the answer !! ))

I tested your code on Android studio and all is working properly including BottomBar
Here is the result :

if you have issue yet it may be related to Theme of your Compose project.

i can see a barely noticeable line above the bottom bar in your second case. How to remove it ?

@Hossein Shahmohammadi: This does not explain the screenshot from the question. As it is right now your answer doesn't address the question, it just states that you experience a different behavior. Your answer should show how the asker can fix their problem.
